# Divide a string into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I'm trying to divide a String into arrays. The overall program is supposed to turn binary into a string but the problem I'm having is dividing the string into arrays. I feel stupid because this seems like a simple thing to do. the binary comes like this "0100100001001001" instead of "01001000" "01001001".

```
public static ArrayList<String> divStr(String str,int div){

    String addable = "";
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length();i++){
      addable += str.charAt(i);
      if(i % div == 0 && i != 0){
        ret.add(addable);
        addable = "";
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

Comment: Would [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use split with regex like so :

```
String[] ret = str.split("(?<=\\G.{" + div +"})");
```

If you want to return a `List` :

```
public static List<String> divStr(String str, int div) {
    return Arrays.asList(str.split("(?<=\\G.{" + div +"})"));
}
```

If you call the method for example :

```
System.out.println(divStr("0100100001001001", 8));
>> [01001000, 01001001]
```

---

If you mean by `div` the number of parts you can change your code to be :

```
public static List<String> divStr(String str, int div) {
    int length = str.length() / div;
    return Arrays.asList(str.split("(?<=\\G.{" + length +"})"));
}
```

then :

```
System.out.println(divStr("0100100001001001", 2));
>> [01001000, 01001001]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your code.
**(1)** The condition `i % div == 0 && i != 0` is wrong because say `div = 8`, it will add the first 9 chars to the list when `i = 8`.
**(2)** If the length of the string `str` is not a multiple of `div` there will be chars left out from the list. 
So change to this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> divStr(String str,int div){
    String addable = "";
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length();i++){
        addable += str.charAt(i);
        if((i + 1) % div == 0){
            ret.add(addable);
            addable = "";
        }
    }
    if (!addable.isEmpty()) ret.add(addable);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with **i % div** which only came once in your code because it starts from 0 and goes to
str.length = 15 it should be replaced by **(i+1) % div**

```
public static ArrayList<String> divStr(String str,int div){

    String addable = "";
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length();i++){
      addable += str.charAt(i);
      if((i+1) % div == 0 && i != 0){
        ret.add(addable);
        addable = "";
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }
```